# Как отобразить PlaceMarkObject на карте (Yandex.MapKit)

Tags: yandexmapkit

я разбираюст с документацией Mapkit. Мне кажется, что такой код должен отображать мой значок на карте

```
    val locationManager = MapKitFactory.getInstance().createLocationManager()
    val image = ImageProvider.fromResource(this.activity,R.drawable.ic_pin_me)
    val placemark = v.mapview.map.mapObjects.addPlacemark(Point(55.723587, 37.569944), image)
    placemark.isVisible = true
    placemark.isDraggable = false

    v.mapview.map.move(CameraPosition(Point(55.723587, 37.569944), 15.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f))
```

но этого не происходит. Подскажите, что не так

Answer (score 1):

Oтображается только определенные виды иконок. Как в `примере.png`.

Answer (score 0):

Сначала нужно обзавестись коллекцией:

```
mapObjects = v.mapView.map.mapObjects.addCollection()
```

И уже в неё добавлять объекты:

```
val placemark = mapObjects.addPlacemark(...)
```

P.S. Да, с документацией у них не очень, поэтому полезно посмотреть код их демо-приложения https://github.com/yandex/mapkit-android-demo